# How can I close the navigation and page bars in OneNote 2010?

Tags: toolbar, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I'm using OneNote 2010 to build a shared input document, and I've saved the page as a .one file in order to share with my correspondent via e-mail.  (Network sharing is not an option).

When I open the .one file, OneNote shows the Navigation Bar:

[image]

and the Pages Bar (is that what it's called?):

[image]

This is really annoying because

1. It's only a single page; I don't need notebook-level navigation
2. I don't want the page scrolling left and right when I'm editing, but
3. It's already a very long page, and having to constrain the width even as much as the bars do when they're "minimized" is detrimental

Is there a way to hide/close these two bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there certainly is.  Open your notebook file then select the View menu at the top then select Full Page.  They will go Bye Bye immediately.  I am assuming if you close it/save it that way it stays that way.  We are both about to find out :)

Comment: So update... it works but not in terms of when it's reopened.  You seem to have to go Full Page view each time.  It seems F11 will do this as a hot key if that helps.

Comment: F11 does what I want to, but it's unfortunate that it's not the default view.  Thanks for the tip!